# When I install Caffe on Mac, there is a fault "clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread' "

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, pthreads, caffe

I feel that all dependences are installed, and I want to install Caffe without GPU, but when I do `make all`, there is an error:

```
CXX src/caffe/util/upgrade_proto.cpp
AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchain/XcodeDefault.xctoolch   ain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(cudnn_conv_layer.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchain/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(cudnn_lcn_layer.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchain/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(cudnn_lrn_layer.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchain/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(cudnn_pooling_layer.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchain/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(cudnn_relu_layer.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchain/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(cudnn_sigmoid_layer.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchain/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(cudnn_softmax_layer.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchain/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(cudnn_tanh_layer.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchain/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a(cudnn.o) has no symbols
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::imread(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      caffe::WindowDataLayer<float>::load_batch(caffe::Batch<float>*) in window_data_layer.o
      caffe::WindowDataLayer<double>::load_batch(caffe::Batch<double>*) in window_data_layer.o
      caffe::ReadImageToCVMat(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int, int, bool) in io.o
  "cv::imencode(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> >&, std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > const&)", referenced from:
      caffe::ReadImageToDatum(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int, int, int, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, caffe::Datum*) in io.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3] Error 1
```

I do not understand why this happens and it seems like my Xcode may have some problems? Could someone help me?

Comment: There are two separate things here: 1) *"clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'"* is an ignoreable (although annoying) compiler **warning** (not error) that you often get with MacOS clang. Ignore it, or suppress it with `-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument` 2) Whereas *"Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: ... clang: error: linker command failed with exit code "* is an actual **error**. Fix that. (Looks like a missing header file to me, so check your `-I...` include paths.)

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate things here:

1. *"clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'"* is an ignoreable (although annoying) compiler **warning** (not error) that you often get with MacOS clang, these days it has pthreads support builtin. Ignore it, or suppress it with `-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument`
2. whereas *"Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: ... clang: error: linker command failed with exit code "* is an actual **error**. Fix that. (Looks like a missing header file to me, so check your `-I...` include paths. I don't know Caffe so I can't comment more on that.)

Answer (score 0):

make sure you install openCV before building caffe.

```
brew install -vd snappy leveldb gflags glog szip lmdb
# need the homebrew science source for OpenCV and hdf5
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install hdf5 opencv
```

please go threw [caffe OS X Installation](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_osx.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem as well. It could be the Makefile.config. Please check the paths you provided for **PYTHON_INCLUDE** and **PYTHON_LIB**.

I had given the brew python path to **PYTHON_INCLUDE** and system path to **PYTHON_LIB**. I also made sure that the caffe python was added to the python path before compiling.Hope this information is of help.